# make the value from .then(value) to an global alue which can used later

Tags: node.js, discord.js

how can i use the value from the first `.then` statement in the second? I want to use d_channel in the second `.then` and in the third

```
message.guild.channels.create('register-'+username[0], {
            type: 'text',
            permissionOverwrites: [{
                id: message.member.user.id,
                allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
            },
            {
                id: "707236888330895380",
                deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
            }], 
        }).then((d_channel) =>{
            const categoryId = '732596048324984863';
            d_channel.setParent(categoryId);
            //channel.delete(100000);
            console.log(d_channel.id)
        }).then(()=>{ console.log(d_channel.id)});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep passing the `d_channel` each time in the promise chain.

```
}).then((d_channel) =>{
            const categoryId = '732596048324984863';
            d_channel.setParent(categoryId);
            //channel.delete(100000);
            console.log(d_channel.id)
            return d_channel // pass it to the next promise in the chain
        }).then((d_channel)=>{ console.log(d_channel.id)});
```

Comment: it doesnt work. i tried it but d_channel is undefined